# Cómo añadir funcionalidad de add, remove y delete a botones en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, eliminar

Me encuentro trabado en mi primer carrito de Javascript, no sé como darle funcionalidad a los botones de sumar restar o eliminar un producto dentro del carrito, dejo el codigo completo puesto que no sabia como priorizar lo importante para la respuesta. Muchas gracias a cualquiera que me pueda dar una mano

Aqui estan los iconos puntualmente

```
   if (cartItems && containerProductos) {
    containerProductos.innerHTML = "";
    Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
        containerProductos.innerHTML += `
      <div class="producto" >
    <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
    <img src="./assets/${item.tag}.png">
    <span>${item.nombre}</span>
    </div>  
    <div class=precio>$${item.precio}</div>
    <div class=cantidad>
    <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
    ${item.enCarrito}
    <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class=total >$${item.enCarrito * item.precio}.00</div>
    `
    });
}
}
onLoadnumeroIcono();
 displaycarritoNav();
```

No se si debo poner algo mas, es mi primer pregunta en stackoverflor y muy muy nuevo en javascript

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: crea un array con los productos, para remover haz un funcion que filtre los productos que no tengan el mismo id del producto removido.